# .NETCF Component that allows entering a signature

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, components

I need a component that will allow me to enter a signature on a Windows Mobile 5 device.

I need to integrate it into my .NETCF program.  I would prefer it be free (getting budget approval takes so long).  (I have seen the "for pay" one by Resco.)

I would need to end up storing the signature in a SQL Server database (it has to be able to serialize).  But I don't want the control to do any of the communications for me.  I just want it to be able to save to some kind of db compatible value.  (I will be saving it in a SQL Server Compact Edition db before sending it to a SQL Server 2008 db)

If anyone has any suggestions I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SDF](http://opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) has [a signature control](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/243ba28c-37a0-1818-ac10-4511dcd6f195.htm) in it.  And the community edition is free (we've had it long enough the code is probably in the old 1.4 code base too).